# Prolog. How to print a matrix according to a dynamic predicate?

Tags: prolog

I have the next matrix:

```
map(1,[[2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
   [3,2,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0],
   [0,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
   [0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]).
```

and a dynamic predicate:

```
:- dynamic visited/2.
```

and this "function" which print the matrix:

```
printEncoded(M) :-
maplist(\X^(maplist(\Y^(Y = 0
                        -> write(' ~ ')
                        ;
           write(' # ')),
                   X),
           nl),
       M).
```

I want to print the matrix according to visited/2 predicate, with this conditions: 
         
           - if visited(X,Y) is true, then print("Value of matrix element")
- if visited(X,Y) is false, then print("~").

How I can do this?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `visited` is dynamic is completely irrelevant here.
I can totally emphasize with your wish to use `maplist` (this would feel more "pythonic" somehow), but in this case you need row and column indices.
If you use `\X^...` and `\Y^...` you get only rows / elements, but not their indices. If you need something like `if-T-then-A-else-B`, you can express it very easily as `(T,A;B)` in Prolog. Here is a rough sketch, with all the necessary recursions written out explicitly (runnable with `swipl`):

```
:- initialization(main).
:- dynamic(visited).

matrix([
  [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [3,2,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0],
  [0,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
  [0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
]).

visited(0, 0).
visited(1, 0).
visited(1, 1).
visited(4, 6).
visited(5, 6).

printMatrix(M) :- printRows(M, 0).
printRows([], _).
printRows([H|T], R) :- 
  printRow(H, R, 0), 
  Rpp is R + 1, 
  printRows(T, Rpp).
printRow([], _, _) :- nl.
printRow([H|T], R, C) :- 
  (visited(R,C), write(H); write("~")),
  write(" "),
  Cpp is C + 1, 
  printRow(T, R, Cpp).

main :- matrix(M), printMatrix(M), halt.
```

Here is the output:

```
2 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
3 2 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 1 ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 0 ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
```

A remark about `dynamic(visited)`: it's questionable whether one really should maintain the track of some global state in this way. This totally pollutes the global database, thus rendering the code not usable as component of larger programs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a problem, swi-prolog is closing when I try to compile your code, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Because it tries to fulfill the `main` predicate. The main predicate contains `halt`. If you want to continue the execution, delete the `halt`, or don't specify anything in the `initialization` at all. Hm, strange, I've found it extremely annoying that the interpreter doesn't just do its work and quit. I prefer to let it run on a separate terminal with `watch -n 1 swipl myScript.pl`, so that it recompiles and runs every second: I find it's much easier to see the changes immediately, than `consulting` something and re-running some queries manually.